# Alternatives to AdeptSQL Diff (for MS SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server-2012

It seems AdeptSQL Diff is not compatible with SQL Server 2012 (at this time). And it is my preferred tool for deploying changes. I realize this is a shopping list but I hope SE won't mind.

I am wondering what are the best alternatives out there and wanted to query the DBAs.

Currently I am evaluating RedGate SQL Compare. It doesn't include data comparison (separate product) though it does generate deployment scripts which is nice. Just want something quick and painless for launching schema changes to production servers. What do you recommend. Thanks!

Comment: Redgate compare = schema, data compare = data. I highly recommend both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) supports SQL Server 2012. 
Haven't tested it on SQL Server 2012, but it works fine on 2008

Answer (score 0):

[Advancor Database Compare](https://www.advancor.com) is a great tool and supports SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I'm sorry but, it is not available today as I seen in its web site: The "Company is closing for business"